# How to add "ns1" prefix all the child node and sub child node of an XML

Tags: java

```
<SOURCE>aa</SOURCE>

<UBSCOMP>hh</UBSCOMP>

<MSGID />

<CORRELID />

<USERID>fff</USERID>

<BRANCH>tt</BRANCH>

<MODULEID />
```

The above xml I have to convert to below soap xml.

```
<ns1:QUERYCUSTOMER_IOFS_REQ xmlns:ns1="name space ">

    <ns1:FCUBS_HEADER>

        <ns1:SOURCE>aa</ns1:SOURCE>

        <ns1:UBSCOMP>hh</ns1:UBSCOMP>

        <ns1:MSGID></ns1:MSGID>
```

can anyone tell me how to add prefix to all the child node of the XML. it should be dynamic.

Comment: Why are u doing it that way? Why is your generated soap message not namespace compliant at first place. Everything you do as replacement will just be dirty and temporary

Answer (score 0):

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("(?<=\\</?)\\b", "ns1:");
```

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated on stack overflow.